# c++ minimum value of vector greater than another value

Tags: c++, vector, max, min

I have a `vector` of `double`s. I wish to find both:

- The minimum value in the vector that is greater than (or equal to) a value `x`.
- The maximum value in the vector that is less than (or equal to) a value `x`.

E.g. If I have a vector:

```
std::vector<double> vec = {0, 1.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0};
```

and a value

```
x = 2.6;
```

I wish to find `1.0` and `3.0`.

What is the most efficient way of doing this?

I have something like:

```
double x1, x2; // But these need to be initialised!!!
double x = 2.6;
for (i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i)
{
  if (vec[i] >= x && vec[i] < x2)
       x2 = vec[i];
  if (vec[i] <= x && vec[i] > x1)
       x1 = vec[i];
}
```

But how can I initialise x1 and x2? I could make x2 the maximum of the vector and x1 the minimum, but this requires an initial pass through the data. Is there any way to do this more efficiently?

EDIT:

A couple of assumptions I think I can/cannot make about the data:

- There are no negatives (i.e. the minimum possible number would be `0`)
- It is not necessarily sorted.

Comment: Is the initial vector sorted, as in your example?

Comment: no, it wont be possible to assume it is sorted.

Comment: You don't need any assumptions on the vector, and you can get away with a single pass (implicit _or_ explicit) :)

Comment: @CompuChip if it is sorted you don't even need a single pass, just a binary search so it's O(ln N). Anyway, this is not the case...

Comment: @DarioP yes in that case you could just use `std::lower_bound` to find one of the indices and find the other one in constant time from that.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`std::lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) :

```
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

template<class ForwardIt, class T>
std::pair<ForwardIt, ForwardIt> hilo(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, T const &value)
{
    if (first != last)
    {
        auto lb = std::lower_bound(first, last, value);
        auto prelbd = std::distance(first, lb) - 1;
        if (lb == last) return{ std::next(first, prelbd), last };
        if (!(value < *lb)) return{ lb, lb };
        if (lb == first)  return{ last, first };
        return{ std::next(first, prelbd), lb };
    }
    return{ last, last };
}
```

Which can be used like:

```
std::vector<double> vec = { -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.0 };
// if not ordered
//std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
double x = 5.0;
auto b = hilo(vec.begin(), vec.end(), x);
if (b.first != vec.end())
{
  std::cout << "First index: " << std::distance(vec.begin(), b.first) 
    << "(value " << *b.first << ")\n";
}
if (b.second != vec.end())
{
  std::cout << "Second index: " << std::distance(vec.begin(), b.second) 
    << "(value " << *b.second << ")\n";
}
```

Comment: `std::upper_bound` does not satisfy the condition "(or equal to)".

Answer (score 2):

To initialize the `x1` and `x2` to min and max of the vector, I would imagine you have no choice but to pass through it, unless you called `std::sort` on the vector first, and ordered in ascending or descending order, then picked the head/tail of the list, depending on your ordering, to initialize both values.

You can also use [`std::min_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) to get the min value out of a containter, or [`std::max_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) to find the max element in a container.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid an extra pass across the whole vector, you could always pick up the maximum possible value for the type you are using (in this case, double). STL gives you a way to do this, see e.g. here:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/limits/numeric_limits/

For your case, try something like:

```
#include <limits>       // std::numeric_limits
.
.
.
double x1 = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
double x2 = std::numeric_limits<double>::min();
.
.
.
// rest of your code
```

Answer (score 2):

Use iterators:

```
auto maxBelowX = vec.end();
for (auto i = vec.begin(); i != vec.end(); ++i)
{
    if (*i <= x && (i == vec.end() || *i > maxBelowX)) {
        maxBelowX = i;
    }
}

if (maxBelowX == vec.end()) {
    std::cout << "There was no element <= x";
}
```

Comment: Is `T = auto`? And do you mean, `maxBelowX = i`?

Comment: thanks for the tip; but this is just semantics (and perhaps performance I dont know), but does not really answer the question

Comment: How do you mean, just semantics? I think this is quite a nice alternative solution that goes outside your box :)

Comment: @jramm you need a special value or an out-of-band boolean that says "there was no value in vec smaller than x". A special value (like `std::numeric_limits` or `NaN`) can interfere with the contents of the vector, but requires no additional storage. The separate boolean flag requires additional storage, but doesn't interfere with the input domain. The `end()` iterator is equivalent to this separate flag.

Comment: @jramm this is not just semantics, this is the answer and IMHO the best one provided so far.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to pass through the vector to get the minimum and maximum value in the vector, since these are still not guaranteed to be less than or greater than `x`, respectively (consider the vector `[1 2 3 4]` for `x = 5` - you can initialize `x1 = 4` but after the loop you will mistakenly think that it is the smallest value `>= 5`).

It seems that what you would need is to initialize `x1` and `x2` to values that will unambiguously flag whether you found a minimum or maximum, where unambiguously means that you cannot mistake them for an actual value in the vector.

One suggestion, as given by Yannis Douros, is to use `std::numeric_limits<double>::min()` and `std::numeric_limits<double>::max()`. 
Or you can just go with

```
x1 = x - 1;
x2 = x + 1;
```

During the loop, `x1` will get overwritten with the first value greater than `x`, so after the loop, all you need to do is check whether `x1 >= x` to know whether you found a minimum. If you have, its value will be `x1`.

Similarly, if `x2` should be `<= x`, then the largest value smaller than `x` is `x2`, if on the other hand `x2 > x` (*i.e.* `x2` is still `x + 1`) and you have not found a maximum.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using [std::partition](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition)

```
std::vector<double> vec = {0, 1.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0};
double x = 2.6;
auto middle = std::partition(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 
    [x](const auto& v){return v < x;});
auto max_lt = *std::max_element(vec.begin(), middle); // = 1
auto min_gt = *std::min_element(middle, vec.end()); // = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following approach

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> v = { 0, 1.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0 };
    double x = 2.6;

    auto minmax = std::make_pair( v.size(), v.size() );

    for ( std::vector<double>::size_type i = 0; i != v.size(); ++i )
    {
        if ( v[i] <= x && ( minmax.first == v.size() || v[minmax.first] < v[i] ) )
        {
            minmax.first = i;
        }
        else if ( x <= v[i] && ( minmax.second == v.size() || v[i] < v[minmax.second]  ) )
        {
            minmax.second = i;
        }
    }

    if ( minmax.first != v.size() )
    {
        std::cout << "The maximum value less than or equal to " << x
                  << " is " << v[minmax.first] << std::endl;
    }

    if ( minmax.second != v.size() )
    {
        std::cout << "The minimum value greater than or equal to " << x
                  << " is " << v[minmax.second] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
The maximum value less than or equal to 2.6 is 1
The minimum value greater than or equal to 2.6 is 3
```

If the vector is sorted then you may use standard algorithm `std::equal_range`.
For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> v = { 0, 1.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0 };
    double x = 2.6;

    auto minmax = std::equal_range( v.begin(), v.end(), x );

    if ( minmax.first == minmax.second )
    {
        if ( minmax.first != v.begin() ) std::advance( minmax.first, -1 );
        else minmax.first = v.end();
    }
    else
    {
        std::advance( minmax.second, - 1 ); 
    }


    if ( minmax.first != v.end() )
    {
        std::cout << "The maximum value less than or equal to " << x
                  << " is " << *minmax.first << std::endl;
    }

    if ( minmax.second != v.end() )
    {
        std::cout << "The minimum value greater than or equal to " << x
                  << " is " << *minmax.second << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output will be the same as shown above.